# How to have common options for multiple y-axes in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have two y-axes in my Highcharts chart. Most of the options are the same; for those ones, do I have to copy-paste it into both array elements or is there a way to avoid that? This is the yaxis part of my code right now (a lot of repetition):

```
 yAxis: [{
                     crosshair: {
                        color: '#FB7F1D'
                    },
                    max: 4000,
                    lineColor: '#767676',
                    gridLineColor: '#767676',
                    minorGridLineColor: '#767676',
                    minorTickColor: '#767676',
                    tickColor: '#767676',
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            color: '#767676'
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'f-value',
                        style: {
                            color: '#767676'
                        }
                    }  
                },
                 //next element
                    {
                    crosshair: {
                        color: '#FB7F1D'
                    },
                    lineColor: '#767676',
                    gridLineColor: '#767676',
                    minorGridLineColor: '#767676',
                    minorTickColor: '#767676',
                    tickColor: '#767676',
                    labels: {
                        format: '${value}',
                        style: {
                            color: '#767676'
                        }
                    },
                    max: 60,
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    alignTicks: false,
                    opposite: true,
                    gridLineColor: '#767676',
                    title: {
                        text: 'Price',
                        style: {
                            color: '#767676'
                        }
                    }
                    }
                ],
```

Comment: I fairly confident that it has to be repeated. If you are looking to beautify the code then I would suggest you create a separate object that holds all the shared information, and use that object + specific options for each axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately doesn't provide a mechanism like `plotOptions` (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions) for axes.

You can either use the solution proposed by @ewolden in the comment below your question or set **global options**:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    xAxis: {
    title: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
        color: '#bada55'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bv7L4o7t/

The main disadvantage of this approach is that these options will be applied to every chart.